# How to show erc721 NFT card images in compatible wallets?

Tags: erc-721, nft

I have created an NFT and now I want to add some metadata e.g card images, that shows in a compatible wallet like trust wallet.

What step is needed next?

Answer (score 5):

Just create a JSON file following the "ERC721 Metadata JSON Schema" specified at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Here is [one simple example](https://tenthousandsu.com/erc721/00050.json) that meets the specification:

```json
{
    "name": "Square #00050",
    "description": "CoinGecko",
    "image": "https://tenthousandsu.com/erc721/00050.png"
}
```

In that example it stores the image at https://tenthousandsu.com/erc721/00050.png

Lastly, just set the `tokenURI` to that URL for your token.

If you are using [the ERC-721 reference implementation](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/mocks/nf-token-metadata-mock.sol) then the `tokenURI` is set [in the `mint` function](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/mocks/nf-token-metadata-mock.sol#L38).

All wallets that are ERC-721 compatible would then recognize that image as associated with the token, and likely display it or link to it.